# Popcorn.js Webmaker timeline

Tags: javascript, mozilla, popcornjs

In [popcorn webmaker project](https://popcorn.webmaker.org/), there is a time line in the bottom of the page and I would like to use this time line. But When I'm searching about time line for popcorn.js, it's always about creating event to happen at X time in the video.

Me, I would like to get the code of the time line, to add band, zoom-in, zoom-out, be able to drag element in time and all others utils implement in this project.

Under [webmaker source code](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn.webmaker.org),  In public/src/ui/ they call it track and in public/src/timeline/, they call it timebar. I still don't get it... I just want to be able to use this tools and apply some modification.

And I don't find any .html that include those script and any container, How do I create back this time line ?